# move text on an image with tcpdf and php

Tags: php, tcpdf

How to you move text along the y axis using tcpdf? $pdf->Write(150 moves it up and down, I just can't figure out left to right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLmgH.png

```
<?php

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


// set margins
//$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
//$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
//$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
//$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set JPEG quality
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);


// Image example with resizing
$pdf->Image('../../edit1forbrad_program.jpg', 10, 10, 480, 680, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

$txt = "Some sample text";
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 16);
$pdf->Write(150, $txt, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
//$pdf->Annotation(83, 27, 10, 10, "Text annotation example\naccented letters test: aaeeiioouu", array('Subtype'=>'Text', 'Name' => 'Comment', 'T' => 'title example', 'Subj' => 'example', 'C' => array(255, 255, 0)));



// -------------------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_009.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually adjust the Y-axis by calling `SetY()` before calling `Write()`.

So for example:

```
$pdf->SetY(30);
$pdf->Write( //Etc. );
```

But in the case of fitting text into a box like that the best thing, in my opinion, would be to create a [MultiCell](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece). You can position a MultiCell by adjusting the X en Y parameters, and a correctly sized MultiCell will make sure no text will go outside of the box, because it will break the line automatically as it reaches the right end of the Cell.